# Overflow hidden breaking translateZ

Tags: css, overflow, css-transforms

### Setup

I have three `div`s using CSS3 translations in all directions within a container `div` that is itself within an outer, fullscreen `div`. The outermost `div`, the full screen one, has `perspective` set on it.

**HTML**

```
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='container ofhidden'>
    <div class='item' id='item1'></div>
    <div class='item' id='item2'></div>
    <div class='item' id='item3'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
  perspective: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.outer .container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 130%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}
.outer .container.ofhidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.outer .container .item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.outer .container .item#item1 {
  background-color: green;
  transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, -10px);
}
.outer .container .item#item2 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
}
.outer .container .item#item3 {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 10px);
}
```

### Problem

The `div` that contains the translated elements has `overflow: hidden;` set on it which disables or ignores the translation in the Z direction while not effecting the other directions.

### Demo

Please see this pen http://codepen.io/aaron/pen/Ihrxj for the code and a button which toggles `overflow: hidden;` to demonstrate the effect.

For those not familiar with HAML, SCSS/Compass, or CoffeeScript, you can click on the name of the preprocessor next to HTML, CSS, and JS to see the generated code in the codepen.

Comment: Update: This is no longer a problem at least in my codepen example. Perhaps it was a webkit bug long fixed.

Comment: As per spec https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-style-property this apparently is by design. Why it's working in webkit, meaning webkit ignoring spec and behaving more towards user expectations, I cannot say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening, but i can suggest a couple of workarounds.

An obvious solution is to set `overflow: hidden;` (if you really need it) on items (either with `.item` or `.container > *`, instead of applying it to the container.

Another option is to position items absolutely. It's not very handy but it might work out for your layout (you can position items absolutely relatively to the container).

In both cases `transform3d` won't be disabled/ignored.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept this. I guess no one really knows _why_ it's happening but these workarounds (and others) will avoid the problem :P.

Comment: It's 2016 now and both the IE10 and FireFox 49.0.2 will disable perspective on an element and render its children flat (z direction=0, but scale remaining!) with overflow:hidden on the element.